# how to use provide in an exported function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

as shown in the below posted code, i want to export the function `GISWSCaller`. i am following the tutorial in [this link](https://logaretm.com/blog/making-the-most-out-of-vuejs-injections/), and i want to create something as indicated in the 3rd code snippet in that link.

the problem i am encountring is, despite the `GISWSCaller.ts` has `import { provide } from 'vue'`, i can not use `provide('GISWSCaller)`. I mean, when i use `provide` i receive a warning in the web-browser.

please let me know how to properly use `provide` in `GISWSCaller` as stated in the aforementioned link.

**note**:

if it is not possible to use `provide` within an exported function, then, please, how the author of the article mentioned in the above posted link has done it!!

**GISWSCaller.ts**:

```
import { provide } from 'vue';
let res = undefined

export default function GISWSCaller(){

  async function fetchURL(params){
    console.log("params:",params);
    
    const splitted = params.split(',')
    if (splitted.length == 4) {
      const response = await fetch('https://xx/xx/getDistanceFromOriginToDestination/' + params)
      res =  await response.json()
      return res
    }
    return false
  }
  
const ctx = {
  fetchURL
}

provide('GISWSContext',ctx)
return fetchURL
}
```

**App.vue. invokation of GISWSCaller.ts**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  <g-i-s-w-s-caller @evtRunWSRouteTest="evtReceiverForRunWSRouteTest"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import GISWSCaller from './composables/GISWSCaller.ts'
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    GISWSCaller
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>
const g = GISWSCaller()

console.log("g:",g['fetchURL']('30.976639,30.056021,30.97775,30.033333')); 
// functions
function evtReceiverForRunWSRouteTest(e) {
  console.log("evt:",e);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The code is fine.  You'll need to be more specific when you say "i can not use `provide('GISWSCaller)`".  That has no meaning in a development context.  How or why can you not use it?  Is there an error?  Does anything happen when you try injecting it in a component somewhere?  What is the full story on how you're using this composable and what is the exact technical problem you're facing?

Comment: @yoduh when I try to use “provide” in the exported function posted in the question above, I receive a warning message in the browser telling me that “provide” is available only in “setup”

Comment: can you show where and how you're calling `GISWSCaller` function?  It all depends on how you're using it.  I made a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-currying-dftmgw?file=/src/Comp.vue).  The actual fetch obviously doesn't work, but the the provide/inject does.

Comment: @yoduh i posted App.vue where GISWSCaller is called...please have a look at it